# Incrementing a PHP variable with click of WordPress Post title

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to write a function that increments a variable, which will later be stored as post meta for the WordPress post, by clicking the posts title. In other words, I want to a create function that keep track of how many times a post title of a certain post is being clicked.

I'm new to using jQuery so I'm trying to figure out how to get the 2 function in PHP and jQuery to interact. I need to process the data in PHP later, which is why I need to do this.

This is what I have so far (PHP):

```
function clickScoreMethod($postid){

    //$clickScore = 0;
    $clickScore = get_post_meta($postid, 'redditclickscore', true);
    $clickScore = $clickScore + 0.25; 
    update_post_meta($postid, 'redditclickscore',$clickScore);

}
```

`$clickScore` is the variable I want to increase by 0.25 every time the post title is clicked. I'm using meta to store it easily per post. If it is simpler, I can also increase the score by just incrementing the variable and then dividing it by 4 when I process it in the PHP later.

The jQuery:

```
$("li.post-item article").each(function(){
    $( ".the-post-container .entry-title" ).click(function() {
        var clickScore = 0.25;
    });
});
```

`.entry-title` is the post title and .post-item-article is basically the blog roll.
I have no idea how to get these two to work together so that I increase the number.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do this.

Your jQuery would look something like this:

```
$("li.post-item article").each(function () {
  $(".the-post-container .entry-title").click(function () {
    var clickScore = 0.25;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/path/to/php/file",
      type: "POST",
      data: { clickScore: clickScore },
      success: function () {
        console.log("Success!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and you would access the variable and do stuff with it with this (in PHP):

```
$clickScore = $_POST["clickScore"]
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will this continuously increment though? Meaning that if I click the post twice, the total will be 0,5 (0.25+0.25) for that post? If so, how will access the clickScore for any single post?

Comment: @user3601991 It depends on how you use it in your PHP. If you want to store the clickScore permanently, you will need to use MySQL queries.